# Is there any way to see the posts I upvoted by tag on my profile page of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page

I can see other posts that were very useful and were upvoted on my profile page. But I don't find any option to see them **by tags.**

Is there any way?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way. Even if you do [a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1191929/votes-by-jonskeet), I don't think you can get the up/downvotes, it only shows favourites and bounties. Things that are public knowledge anyway. I had a look at what data you get back when you look at your votes from your profile but it doesn't seem possible to even scrape that. You only get the post title, the date and (if you expand it), the body of the post itself. You don't get tag information, unless you then fetch the main question...

Comment: *"Even if you do a SEDE query, I don't think you can get the up/downvotes, it only shows favourites and bounties."* correct, @VLAZ , I actually tried to write a SEDE, and then (once finished) foolishly remembered that SEDE doesn't provide details of who voted at all, frustratingly. If only people weren't so immature about internet points, and therefore who voted could be publicly available. /sigh

Comment: @Larnu or at least if you could view *your* votes. You can log in using your SE account, after all, so you could gain access to only your data. It's probably a higher hurdle implementation-wise but at least if you could to some sort of private query you could turn the option to view your own votes.

Comment: The accounts for SEDE and the rest of the community aren't linked though (*"Data Explorer doesn't participate in the Stack Exchange network authentication scheme, so your account here is completely separate. Don't worry though, you can update your name in your profile at any time!"*), so that would likely be difficult, @VLAZ .

Comment: @Larnu ah...OK. I'm actually quite new to *using* SEDE - only linked my account there last week for a single query. The one I did now is my second one. I didn't notice it's not actually directly linked. So...yeah, harder still.